# Let $G$ be the non-abelian group $G = \{e, x, x^2, y, yx, yx^2 \}$ with $|x| =3$ and $|y| = 2$, show that $xy = yx^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the non-abelian group $G = \{e, x, x^2, y, yx, yx^2 \}$ with $|x| =3$ and $|y| = 2$, show that $xy = yx^2$.

I know that $\langle x \rangle = \{x, x^2, e\}$ and $\langle y \rangle = \{y, e\}$, but I can't figure out a way to relate this.  I've to prove this by showing $y^{-1}xy = x^2$, but I figure a way to do this either.

Comment: Did you leave out $x^2$ from your original description of $G$? Right now it has order five and hence is abelian. And are you sure these are the right relations? Right now it looks a lot like the dihedral group, where you would be proving that $(xy)^{-1}=yx^2$.

Comment: Added it back in.

Comment: I added a second question as well

Comment: You just have to figure out which of the given elements $xy$ is. It can't be $yx$ because then the group would be abelian. You similarly need to rule out $x,x^2,y$ and $e$.

Comment: Oop, i see that everything's ok if what I said is true since $xy=(xy)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 6):

$xy \in G$, so $xy$ should be one of the elements from the set $\{e,x,x^2,y,yx,yx^2\}$.

If $xy = x$, then $y = e$, contradiction with $|y|=2$.
If $xy = y$, same $x = e$, contradiction wth $|x|=3$. (Similar case for $x^2$).
If $xy = yx$, then they commute and therefore group will be Abelian.

Therefore $xy = yx^2$.

Comment: You miss the case $xy=e$.

Comment: that part is left as an exercise to the reader

Comment: It is the hardest of them all.

Comment: $xy = e$,$x = y^{-1} = y$, but $x$ and $y$ have different orders.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I was doing something way more complicated. Forgot that $y$ was it own inverse.

Comment: Does it makes sense that since $G$ is a group and $G = \langle y \rangle \langle x \rangle = \{yx : y \in \langle y \rangle, x \in \langle x \rangle \} \Rightarrow \langle y \rangle \langle x \rangle = \langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle.$  Then the only elements that are different between $\langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$ and $\langle x \rangle \langle y \rangle$ are $xy, yx, x^2y,$ and $yx^2$.  If $xy= yx$ then the group is abelian, then $xy$ must equal $yx^2$?  I figure I didn't have to check all the cases that way.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, its Dihedral group of order 3. $$ D_{2n}=\{e,r,r^2,\dots,r^{n-1},s,sr,sr^2,\dots,rs^{n-1}\}$$ and it has the property that $$r^is=sr^{-i}\ \  i=0,1,2,\dots,n.$$ For proving the above statement we can use the method of induction. Or one can see the book **Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote pageno. 25 Third Edition.**

So this follows your question directly.